# Easiest way to exit Ansible playbook while debugging

Tags: ansible

Say I'm debugging an Ansible playbook and want to quit after a given task (and not run through all of the following tasks). Is there any one-line magic command available, or do I have to manually create an exit/assert task?

From the `ansible-playbook` manual, I see that there is a `--start-at-task=START_AT` flag, but I don't see anything like an 'end-at' counterpart.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `- pause:` might suit.

> Pauses playbook execution for a set amount of time, or until a prompt
>   is acknowledged. All parameters are optional. The default behavior is
>   to pause with a prompt. You can use `ctrl+c` if you wish to advance a
>   pause earlier than it is set to expire or if you need to abort a
>   playbook run entirely. To continue early: press `ctrl+c` and then `c`. To
>   abort a playbook: press `ctrl+c` and then `a`.

http://docs.ansible.com/pause_module.html

Or just a straight `- fail:` if you will certainly not want to continue.

If you want a block of tasks to execute, you can use tags and `--with-tags:`. Ansible v2 will have proper code blocks so you can use a single `when:` for multiple tasks.

Answer (score 31):

`- meta: end_play`

[`end_play` (added in 2.2) causes the play to end without failing the host.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html)

Comment: This ends a _play_ not a _playbook_.

Comment: @BradSolomon what is the difference? Because for some reason, `end_play` has no effect in my playbook.

Answer (score 8):

`ansible-playbook --step` will let you confirm each task you want to run and stop execution whenever you want.